# Cron job at three distinct times

Tags: magento-1.8, crontab

How do you execute a cron to run at 9 am, 1 pm and 3.30 pm

My code is

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <dotsquareexportcron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/60 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>export/observer::setStatus</model>
            </run>
        </dotsquareexportcron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Currently it is working per 60 mintues

Please suggest how it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be achieved but is quite complex to do.

What about 9,1 and 3?  `0 9,13,15 * * *`

Answer (score 1):

You can check links below:

- http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference
- http://crontab-generator.org/

In your case: 0 9,13,15 * * * => 9AM, 1PM and 3PM